How perform successive fetch() requests that build upon previous responses?
I apologize in advance about any obvious issues, I'm kind of fumbling my way through this at the moment and feel a bit in over my head.
I'm attempting to perform a fetch request in JavaScript using an asynchronous function that makes takes the result of a previous asynchronous function as an argument. The first function works fine, and delivers the Unique ID I need to progress into chaining multiple API calls together. When attempting to use it in another API call, I'll be told that the Object I'm trying to pass as an argument is a promise.
Here's the functioning code for the first fetch request.
    var gameName = 'Death in Taxes'; // Input by a user, stored as variable here for development.
    var tagLine = 'NA1';  // Input by a user, stored as variable here for development.

    fetchPuuid(gameName, tagLine); // Calls function

    async function fetchPuuid(gameName, tagLine){

       //Creates URL
       const apiURL = `https://americas.api.riotgames.com/riot/account/v1/accounts/by-riot-id/${gameName}/${tagLine}`;
       const queryParams = {
          api_key: 'RGAPI-c6450472-ed11-4c53-baa0-f6f8d739cdf5' // Changes every 24 hours
       };
       const queryString = new URLSearchParams(queryParams).toString();
       const fullUrl = `${apiURL}?${queryString}`;

       try{
          const response = await fetch(fullUrl);

          if(!response.ok){
             throw new Error('Could not fetch puuid');
          }
    
          const data = await response.json();
          puuid = data.puuid;
          return puuid;
       }
       catch(error){
          console.error(error);
       }
    }


When I attempt to use the function and store the response in an object const puuid = fetchPuuid(gameName, tagLine); then attempting to use that object returns a promise. Specifically it's labeled as an [object Promise] when used as a variable in the fetchMatchByPuuid function.
So for example calling the below function with fetchMatchByPuuid(fetchPuuid(gameName, tagLine)); fails.
    async function fetchMatchByPuuid(puuid){
       const apiURL = `https://americas.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v5/matches/by-puuid/${puuid}/ids`;
       const queryParams = {
          api_key: 'RGAPI-c6450472-ed11-4c53-baa0-f6f8d739cdf5'
       };
       const queryString = new URLSearchParams(queryParams).toString();
       const fullUrl = `${apiURL}?${queryString}`;
 
       try{
          const response = await fetch(fullUrl);
 
          if (!response.ok){
             throw new Error('Could not fetch Match IDs');
          }
 
          const data = await response.json();
          console.log(data);
       }
       catch(error){
       console.error(error);
       }
    }

After looking around I understand that this is simply the nature of the fetch() request as it's asynchronous. Still I know there must be some way to use the information you get back, and I've been scouring the internet for several hours to no avail.
I've tried quite a few things, though all have felt as though I'm simply throwing stuff at the wall and seeing what sticks. Something that confused me was what seems to be an alternate way of writing the code using something called "Promise syntax", which has arrows used in the code? At a glance, very confusing and I can't tell if it's simply outdated or not.
So I've tried to simply store the result of the first function into an object, which as mentioned does not work. Instead of working as an object it returns a promise; fair enough. Next I tried calling the function inside of the second function. So inside of fetchMatchByPuuid() I would call fetchPuuid() and assign the result to an object which I would then call further down in the function, which also gave a promise. Next I tried to use the await keyword when calling the function inside another function, which also returned a promise.
I read elsewhere on this site that it could be resolved using a .then callback, but I think that's done in the other format (Promise syntax) and I don't even know if it applies to my code.
Lastly I even tried to consolidate the functions into a larger string of fetch requests in a single function but that gave me a stack error and I quickly abandoned that idea.
I'm confident there's a simple and understandable answer out there that I'm simply struggling to understand, or may even have staring me in the face but at the moment it simply isn't cooperating.

Either fetchMatchByPuuid(await fetchPuuid(gameName, tagLine)) or fetchPuuid(gameName, tagLine).then(fetchMatchByPuuid)

I'm both incredibly grateful and somewhat frustrated, but that worked immediately. Thanks so much @Phil. I'll try to look into why that worked so I can better understand promises and how to use them, but it looks like the trick here is using the .then() method. Hopefully I'm able to find some great resources on my own, but if you have anything off the top of your head are there any good places to start reading up on the solution you offered and how it works?

The duplicate link at the top of your post has some excellent information on the topic
